# What is the difference between the following two multipliers in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

What is the difference between the following two multipliers?
My code and output as following:

```
>>> print np.dot(np.array([1,2]), np.array([[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]))
[15 18 21]
>>> print np.dot(np.array([[1,2]]), np.array([[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]))
[[15 18 21]]
```

So I want to know if these two formulas are the same meaning, if not, what is the meaning of them?

Comment: `np.array([[1,2]])` is 2D.

Comment: What's the actual question here? As in, what part do you not understand? Do you not know that `array([[1, 2]])` and `[[15 18 21]]` are 2D? Or not understand why multiplying a 1x2 matrix by a 2x3 matrix gives a different result than multiplying a 2-vector by a 2x3 matrix? Or…?

Comment: I know that array([[1, 2]]) and [[15 18 21]] are 2D array, but I don't know why they are 2D matrix? And my actual question is why multiplying a 1x2 matrix by a 2x3 matrix gives a different result than multiplying a 2-vector by a 2x3 matrix?

Comment: Do you see a connection between the shape the inputs and the shape of the outputs? There's a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant section from the `dot` documentation is:

> If `a` is an N-D array and `b` is an M-D array (where `M>=2`), it is a
>     sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last axis of `b`::

```
np.dot(np.array([[1,2]]), np.array([[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]))
[[15 18 21]]

(1,2) dot with (2,3) => (1,3)
```

The last axis of `a` is 2, as is the 2nd to the last of `b`.

```
np.dot(np.array([1,2]), np.array([[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]))
[15 18 21]

(2,) dot with (2,3) => (3,)
```

Same last axis of `a` and 2nd to the last of `b`.

A (4,2) dot with (2,3) would produce a (4,3) array.

Or with a 3d first array:

```
In [284]: np.dot(np.ones((4,3,2)),np.ones((2,3))).shape
Out[284]: (4, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
np.dot(np.array([[1,2]]) is matrix 2D
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: what is the meaning of these two formulas?

Comment: because [[1,2]] is matrix 2D but have element = 0 so result is similar